# Android Studio MAC 4.2 beta 3 ADB Issues

Tags: android, macos, adb

i searched and noticed lots of issues with ADB recently, i tried all the answers with no success..

my Version is updated
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as /Users/ME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

i can use it, i was testing my Watch with Wi-fi last week all ok..but this week

i get to connect to device

but when i click debug --select the watch

i get a time out

i also tried Killing-Restart location of the tool is good.

i can see the list of devices

when i try to install with PUSH

**i get adb: connect error for write: closed**

in Event Log i see

**Failed to start monitoring 10.0.0.241:5555**

or
**Error during Sync: Unable to open sync connection!**

then i get

2:39 p.m.   Error
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Retry

2:39 p.m.   Session 'wear': Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Retry

but when i try reconnect or connect says Already connected

im wondering if i should install the Canary version
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 4 available

I know version 4.1.1 had issues and they say they fixed in 4.2

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours of googling..lol

only way to have a persistent connection is to use Debug over Bluetooth

then:

adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub

adb devices should see localhost:4444

adb connect localhost:4444

and done!

thx